# JQuery UI DatePicker showing Year from 2004 only

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jquery datepicker, I have to show in this format mm/yy, I have implemented it accordingly,but the calendar is displaying the starting year 2004, I want it to display from 1980, how can I do that [Fiddler Code](http://jsfiddle.net/JTL3M/)
This is my datepicker code

```
 $("#txtbox").datepicker({
                prevText: "",
                nextText: "",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                }
            });

<input type="textbox" id="txtbox">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the [`yearRange` option](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange). Add `yearRange: "1980:2014",` (or whatever start and end years you need):

```
 $("#txtbox").datepicker({
     prevText: "",
     nextText: "",
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     showButtonPanel: true,
     dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
     yearRange: "1980:2014",
     onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
         var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
         var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
         $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
     }
 });
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/S3GT7/)**

Comment: just a little note. Select a date. then select the date picker again. why is the previously selected date not selected?